# Recommended way to connect C++ Qt application with Google AdWords API

Tags: c++, python, qt, soap, google-ads-api

What is the recommended way of connecting  C++ Qt application with Google AdWords API? There are many [client libraries (java, python, C#, others)](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries), but none of them is C++ based. So I can:

1. Use an external program written in one of supported languages. It brings many problems with error handling, concurrency and portability (Windows and Mac in my case)
2. Use JavaScript library with QtWebKit, but it seems to be an overkill.
3. Make my own implementation of a SOAP client. It's going to be buggy.
4. Use [QtSOAP](https://github.com/commontk/QtSOAP), but I don't think it supports Qt 4.8.
5. Embed python in C++. I've never done it, so I don't know what problems to expect.
6. Find other way.

I need to use almost all of the API capabilities. So which approach is least error-prone?

Comment: May be javascript client will work with [QtScript](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qtscript.html)?

Comment: For a non-buggy c++ implementation of SOAP try [Apache Axis](http://ws.apache.org/axis/)

Comment: There is also gSoap http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html

Comment: @Gigi, gsoap suits my needs better than Axis. I've used gSoap in my former projects :) Anyway. These are only SOAP clients, not Google API client libraries. It takes time to connect them to Google API and it is going to be buggy (for instance language handling in API is quite complicated).

Comment: There is a small example of low level access [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/#soap), but it say _"SOAP+XML would be impractical for building a real-world application"_

Comment: @Gigi Yes I know. I've learned it the hard way :) Implementing half of the functionality with twice of the budget. I'm trying not to make the same mistake twice.